# building qt5 on raspberry pi3 failed

Tags: raspberry-pi, qt5, raspbian

I enabled `gstreamer 1.0`, but it failed with the message:

`ERROR: Feature 'gstreamer_1_0' was enabled, but the pre-condition 'libs.gstreamer_1_0' failed.`

This is my `configure` script:

`/configure -v -opengl es2 -device linux-rasp-pi-g''+ -device-option CROSS_COMPILE=/usr/bin/ -opensource -confirm-license -optimized-qmake -reduce-exports -release -qt-pcre -make libs -prefix /usr/local/qt5 -no-pch -gstreamer 1.0 -nomake examples -nomake tests &> output_configure`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same issue. After installing `gstreamer-1.0` on Raspberry Pi and copying the libs to the host system, make sure you fix relative links in your `sysroot` directory.

Configuring Qt when building from source produces `config.cache` file. If you delete it, `./configure` script will reconfigure everything. This is how you can identify broken symlinks, because it will try to compile a minimal program. For example my installation failed on missing `libm.so`, which was a symlink to a non-existing file.

Running `./sysroot-relativelinks.py sysroot` relinked all the symlinks **after** installing `gstreamer-1.0` and so Qt was able to find the libs.